# how can I refresh a token retrieved with implicit grant flow

Tags: api, authentication, token, spotify

I am using [implicit grant flow with the Spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#implicit-grant-flow).

How am I supposed to refresh the token that is returned ? 
Since it is said to expire in 3600 seconds:
(below is what I extract from the redirect url)

```
  access_token
    :
    "BQCLAQdVW7cNbTz8U8bs-93q4yLWgOluIXe01WpUS6sdg19cNiqbYXG5sMLanAyhNdGT667xR4XvMKVfIzwIYz8iEHSHbrENbLcqIgGeTCHCPH3TWQlsLq4hbYm1S9XxehZSKwKful5ZHr44FQD0VnLm8QMCjp5t"
    expires_in
    :
    "3600"
    type
    :
    "access_token"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is stated in the Spotify API Documentation on [Authorization Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/):

[image: Spotify API Documentation]

The **Implicit Grant** flow does not have access to token refresh. Only **Authorization Code** flow can refresh tokens.